# How I can search in database for a category given in url?

Tags: magento2, database, category

Upon development I want to reindex only specific categories because reindexing takes too long.

Therefore I am whipping a quick commang where I need to provide a category url and from that triggerring via object manager the reindexing of products and anything else required for this particular category.

```
namespace Pcmagas\Tasks\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;


class PartialCategoryReindexer extends Command
{

    public function __construct(ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        parent::__construct(null);
    }


    public function execute(InputInterface $input,OutputInterface $output)
    {
       $url = $input->get('url');
       $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    
       // Trigger reindex here
    }

}
```

But how I can search for categories based upon url?

Comment: Have you found a solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to check the RewriteUrl entity matching url_rewrite table, there are located all the rewrite for product and categories. So you should be able to find in the path your category path and from that to retrieve the id of the category to then retrieve it the normal way.

Comment: Well some may have redirect_url some may not. As fas as I undestand I must check firstt if url path matches the `\/catalog\/category\/view\/id\/(\d)+/` regex first because it may not have url rewrite. If refeg matches I remove it first and then I must the intval fo the modified path.

Comment: Also looking at the table `url_rewrite` we neas also to filter any record by `entity_type='category'` and the `entity_id` is the category id

Comment: well if there is no rewrite then the id of the category is already on the url as you said so there is no really issue to find it there but indeed you are right :)

Comment: Also regex has a typo. The correct one is: `/\/catalog\/category\/view\/id\/(\d)+/`